# wpf listview item updated, property event handler is null

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I've got a WPF ListView where I add objects that have both strings and images. The image is supposed to be something like a star where it is conditionally displayed depending on the other contents of the object. In my XAML, I bound it to a property called "Brand" that returns a BitmapImage. If I always try to show the image, everything works fine. If I try to conditionally show the image (via some C#), I can't get the ListView to update.

What I've tried is adding INotifyPropertyChanged to the object that is added into the ListView so that I can manually trigger the event whenever I want the image to appear. The problem is that the event is always null. It's like the ListView is not subscribing to it.

```
    <ListView Name="MyListView" Grid.Row="3" SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>                    
                <GridViewColumn Header="Brand">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Brand}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

The following 2 lines are how I add my object to the ListView. The data is read out of a file and I omitted some of the variable setting.

```
LineItem li = new LineItem();
MyListView.Items.Add( li );
```

This is what the class looks like minus the other properties.

```
public class LineItem : IComparable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool PersistedBrand { get { return m_brand; } 
        set { 
            m_brand = value;
            Brand = null;
            //PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Brand")); 
        } }

    public BitmapImage Brand
    {
        get
        {
            if (ShowBrand)
            {
                return s_brandImage;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Brand")); 
             // EXCEPTION HERE ABOVE!
        }
    }
}
```

Am I making a mistake in my understanding here regarding how the binding is supposed to work? Any suggestions are appreciated.

mj

EDIT 1 I added more code.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you should *always* check whether an eventhandler is null first (as per Johan's answer).

Comment: I think we're going to need to see more of your view model class and/or more of your XAML.

Comment: I updated the code. It's really simple. There were no other XAML changes worth noting since they only are related to other items on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the handler is null before invoking:

```
public BitmapImage Brand
{
    get
    {
        // ...
    }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, _brand)) return;
        _brand = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about that one. But why is it null?

Comment: It is null when nothing is subscribing to it.

Comment: I think OP is trying to ask why there are no subscribers.

Comment: For example, if you are setting the property before your view model has been bound to the view.

Comment: Yeah, could be the order of things happening. I think raising the event after nullcheck might solve the issue.